# Why there is 3 phase mains input for this AC/DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply

Here is the specs:
http://www.linmot.com/fileadmin/doc/Accessories_Controller/ps_S01-72-1000_e_recent.pdf

This power supply outputs adjustable DC. But why it has 3 line inputs and an earth??

Comment: ... Because sometimes industrial facilities need AC/DC conversion too.

Comment: ok but why 3 phase input for a DC output. 1 phase exists everywhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1kW is a high enough load that the balanced 3-phase circuit is an advantage.

Another advantage is that the filter capacitors need be much smaller for 3-phase, since a the output of a full-wave 3-phase bridge has less than 15% p-p ripple without any filtering at all. That would generally mean lower cost and longer MTBF for the power supply.

Comment: I never saw before generating a single DC output by using 3 phase alternating voltage. It is much more complicated to manufacture I guess. But whats the theory behind? How ,s that 3 phase converted to DC?

Comment: In the simplest form it's just two addition cheap diodes and an input terminal, really almost nothing. A single phase full wave rectifier has 4 diodes, a three phase 6. If there is power factor correction it might be more expensive, but I don't see anything about PF correction on that datasheet. Many smaller (up to maybe 5-10HP) inverter motor controllers will work from 3-phase or (derated significantly) from single phase.

Comment: sorry but im not that deep in the subject. i might be repeating myself. but the link I sent u is a variable power  supply which outputs dc voltage range for a motor drive. why on earth they just dont use a simple dc adapter to power a motor driver. why would one need 3 phases to obtain a dc output? i dont know how to ask it more clearly.

Comment: Because the electric company will charge you extra for drawing from phases unevenly.